# How to restart Handler / Runnable on method call?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using a method to instantiate a new Handler object and kicking off a method to do some task in the allocated time. The problem is, this timer is not restarted for each method call and any lingering time is continued with subsequent calls.

I am wondering how to fix this. This is my method:

```
private void doTask() {
    viewModel.getFeedBackMessage().set("Calculating ...");
    viewModel.fetchData();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (viewModel.getData() == null) {
                viewModel.getFeedbackMessage().set("Failure.");
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 90000);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 90000);

            }
        }
    }, 90000);
}
```

Edit:

```
new Thread(() -> {
        int elapsedTime = 0;
       while (elapsedTime < 90000) {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
           } catch (Exception ex) {}
           if (currentLocation != null) {
               break;
           }
           elapsedTime += 1000;
       }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Can you explain more? Why are you call remove callback and post delayed in both cases if/else. Removed is meant to cancel a future task or that future task is already being executed. So, the remove callback call is useless in my opinion.

Comment: Basically, if the data was found before the allocated time, I want to stop the Handler and if it doesn't find the data, then I still want to stop the Handler

Comment: What you are posting is a delayed task that will be executed once instead you stop it before. But you can not stop the task inside the task itself. The remove callback has to be outside the delayed task, unless I am missing something.

Comment: How can I execute this timer task every method call?

Comment: Sorry, I really did not understand the use case. What do you mean by timer task? doTask()? Can you rewrite your logic using a simple sequential/blocking code written on one single method without involving threading? Maybe you don't need posting a delayed task.

Comment: I just want to attempt a task for x duration and if the data is not returned in that time, cancel the request.

Comment: Okay I see. You are then using a wrong approach. In this type of scenario, you can use a do/while loop in which you check at each iteration if you have data available  (this check must be short and non blocking), and then sleep the thread for some interval (let's say one second), after sleep you increment an elapsed integer variable that keeps track of total time you spent in the loop. If elapsed time is greater then your timeout value (90000), then you quit the loop. If inside the loop you receive data, you can then quit the loop using break.

Comment: This loop is blocking as you may suspect. In order to avoid blocking the GUI, you can for example run it on async task or thread

Comment: Can you check my edit to see if it's right?